# Why arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc and not arm-none-eabi-gcc when compiling Linux kernel and uBoot?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, u-boot, abi

I have some experience compiling bare metal code for ARM cortex-m devices as well as the Linux kernel, uBoot, and applications for the Beaglebone Black (BBB) (more featured ARM with MMU, for those living under a rock). It makes sense to me that the cortex-m code should be compiled using arm-none-eabi-gcc (as there is no OS) and the application code for the BBB should be compiled with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (as there is an OS, for which system calls can be made and program loaders and shared objects can be utilized).

What I don't understand is why uBoot and the kernel also should be compiled with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. In my mind, uBoot at least, is a bare metal program with no fancy OS to account for. This has been bugging me for sometime, but I can't find an answer. Is there anyone out there that can enlighten me?

Comment: Where did you learn this *"uBoot [sic] and the kernel also should be compiled with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc"*?    I've seen U-Boot and the Linux kernel compiled with the same toolchain (e.g. in Buildroot) presumably because of convenience.  But I typically use a baremetal toolchain for bootloaders such as U-Boot (i.e. I build two toolchains).

Comment: I just assumed from examples such as [this](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_U-Boot_User's_Guide#Building_U-Boot). Are you saying that uBoot can actually be compiled with either? What about the kernel?

Comment: When compiling .c into .o, the ABI you choose affects which registers are used for parameters, stack-layout etc.

When linking the .o into an executable, the ABI have a default linker script and helper objects. But both the kernel and probably u-boot provides their own linker scripts etc, so the ABI for this step is not so important

Comment: This question has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956680/difference-between-arm-none-eabi-and-arm-linux-gnueabi

Comment: @JoshuaDeWeese [processors.ti.wiki.com EOL](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors/f/processors-forum/916040/eol-of-processors-wiki-ti-com-resource). Link dead. Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_U-Boot_User's_Guide#Building_U-Boot).

Answer (score -2):

U-Boot was designed to mirror the Linux design philosophy as much as possible. It uses the same configuration system, general directory structure, etc. It shares some APIs with Linux - see the include/linux directory. As the comments above mention, the ABI compatibility doesn't matter at this point, but using a Linux compiler isn't philosophically inappropriate for U-Boot.